# How to write select query in moodle

Tags: php, mysql, moodle

This is my sql query:

```
select * from user_tb;
```

How can I convert it to a Moodle query format.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

```
$users = $DB->get_records_sql('SELECT * FROM {user}');
```

or

```
$users = $DB->get_records('user');
```

See the database documentation here http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Data_manipulation_API#Getting_an_hashed_array_of_records